# number of posts per page + random + exclude categories

Tags: query-posts, pre-get-posts

I have the following code in my home.php

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand' . '&cat=-182,-184'); ?>
```

query_posts seems not the best solution. What would be the best way pre_get_post or WP Query.

Highly appreciated if you could also write the correct code.

Kind regards,

Yves

Comment: Did you have a look at [the ingenious chart](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/15680) by @Rarst?

Answer (score 2):

[pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in your child themes functions file is the best in my opinion.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_custom_get_posts' );

function wpsites_custom_get_posts( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {

$query->set( 'cat', '-182,-184' );

$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '12' );

$query->set( 'orderby', 'RAND' );
    }
}
```

This method is more flexible in my opinion.

Comment: TIL this is the best solution for editing main loop. [Source](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `new WP_Query`. [Here's why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Here's an example of what you might try:

```
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'category__not_in' => array(182, 184)
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) { while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    // Do loop stuff here

endwhile; }

wp_reset_query();
```